# How to read incremental Delta Lake data from access through Lake Formation through AWS Glue Job?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue, delta-lake

We had a system where we wrote the data in Delta Lake format in bucket A of Amazon S3 and then that same data's latest version could be read as incremental from S3 using AWS Glue and processed for further use.

Example:
[image]

Now, there is a change in the way access to read is given, it is now through Lake Formation, wherein, we give fine grained access, now, the challenge is, Delta Lake tables are no more directly accessible but through Glue (Crawled and then table formed). Now, the query is, how to read incremental [after a certain point in time] or versioned data from that (as the Delta functions are no more directly usable.

Been through this code (below), but it doesn't give the understanding of Delta/version based read from Glue directly (without using Spark APIs).

```
# Example: Read a Delta Lake table from Glue Data Catalog

from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)

df = glueContext.create_data_frame.from_catalog(
    database="<your_database_name>",
    table_name="<your_table_name>",
    additional_options=additional_options
)
```

Also, there is not much of the AWS official documentation talking about the same. Please suggest.